# comment box works only with interval ? tennor connection. Grasshopper Python

Tags: python, vector, range, rhino, grasshopper

I want to create boxes because I want to do an tenor connection between the 2 objects. How can divide an interval with numbers. Because the box comment only work with intervals. Or do someone have another solution for the geometry of a tenor connection.

```
import rhinoscriptsyntax as rs
import Rhino.Geometry as rg

 class Constr_Tenon():
    def __innit__(self , mortise , tenons , con_lines_vec , b_plane , new_beam , tenon):
        global con_lines
        self.mortise
        self.tenons = []
        self.con_lines_vec
        self.b_plane 
        self.new_beam
        self.tenon 
        self.tenon_newpos
        self.new_beam = rg.Box( b_plane, length, width, thickness )
        self.con_lines_vec = rg.Vector3d( rg.Line.PointAt(con_lines, 1 ) - rg.Line.PointAt( con_lines, 0 ))
        self.b_plane = rg.Plane( points, self.con_lines_vec )
        self.tenon = rg.Box( b_plane, length, width, thickness/n_tenons )
        for t in range(n_tenons):
            self.tenon_newpos = rg.Box.RepositionBasePlane( self.tenon, points + (thickness/n_tenons)*t)
            self.tenons.append(self.tenon_newpos)


tenons = []
con_lines_vec = rg.Vector3d( rg.Line.PointAt(con_lines, 1 ) - rg.Line.PointAt( con_lines, 0 ))
run = rg.Plane( points, con_lines_vec )
#tenon = rg.Box( b_plane, length, width, thickness/n_tenons )
tenon = rg.Box( b_plane, length, width, [num/n_tenons for num in thickness2])
for t in range(n_tenons):
    tenon_newpos = rg.Box.RepositionBasePlane( self.tenon, points + (thickness2/n_tenons)*t)
    tenons.append(self.tenon_newpos)
```

Comment: Please remove the rhino tag, as this question doesn't relate to Rhino (but relates to rhino3d)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear but to get numbers within an interval you can call the `ParameterAt()` method on an interval object. So something like this

```
it = Rhino.Geometry.Interval(13,16)
nums = list()
for i in range(4):
    nums.append(it.ParameterAt(i * 1/3.0))
```

`nums` will be a list of numbers `[13,14,15,16]`